# PHP regex to cut out everything between defined tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get a regex that finds everything between those h4 tags. So i need an array that contains two paragraphs in the first element, one in the second, three in the third, and so on. There can be all kind of html between the h4 tags.

The one below is not working.

```
$a = preg_match_all("#<h4>(.*?)</p>.*?<h4>#s", $description, $m);
```

---

```
<h4>Lorem ipsum </h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<h4>Lorem ipsum </h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<h4>Lorem ipsum </h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<h4>Lorem ipsum </h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
```

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: You need to stop and [read why using regex like this is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). If that doesn't convice you [maybe this will](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: Well it's sure that there will be h4 tags and i need only the text between.

Comment: In regex, `.` doesn't match newline characters unless you tell it to. Irregardless, you may want to try an html parser instead. More work to set up but, better reaults. [Here's a list of parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$subject = "Your HTML"; //replace with actual HTML
$pattern = "/<\\/h4>(((?!<h4>).)*)/mis";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

`$matches` is then an array of arrays containing all the text found between `h4` tags globally.

Comment: allthoug https://regex101.com/r/aV7mQ4/1 has trouble with it, it works on my side.

Comment: That's because for PHP we have to escape the first backslash and replace the `g` modifier with a call to `prep_match_all`. Here is a link to regex 101 with it set up: https://regex101.com/r/vC1vU4/1